# Whats the recommended Firewall for Linux? APF or UFW?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I just came across APF which seems to be a really good firewall... Whats the best? UFW or APF? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, your better option is to learn NetFilter/IPTables if you're going to admin Linux systems.

As for the question at hand, I'm not familiar with APF, but last I checked UFW has serious limitations for anything but desktop deployment. It had no ability to differentiate between different interfaces, making it useless for forwarding traffic.